# awk to remove lines with multiple duplicated columns fields but with certain pattern in other column field

Tags: awk, sed

Basically if first 3 columns have the same values, I want to keep all rows that do not have forth column value="-". In this case, I want to remove first row, but keep the next 2 rows..

```
   A B C -
   A B C D1
   A B C D2
   AA BB CC D3
   AB BC CD D4
   FA FB FC -
   GA GB GC DN
```

Expected output:

```
   A B C D1
   A B C D2
   AA BB CC D3
   AB BC CD D4
   FA FB FC -
   GA GB GC DN
```

I can understand

```
   awk '!(seen[$1,$2,$3]++  && $4 == "-")'
```

doesn't remove any line, but how to modify the condition so that the first line will be remnoved?

I still want to keep "FA FB FC -" because there are no other rows with first 3 columns as "FA FB FC".

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Also your question is not clear please do add more details on it.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts. It is still not clear@td17 You need to have 3 column values same along with number of field should be equal or more than 4 right?

Comment: What is the use of the first 3 fields?  You can just check the last field.

Comment: edited the post, hopefully it makes a bit more sense..

Comment: @td17, I am wondering why you are using this part `seen[$1,$2,$3]++ ` in your code?

Comment: If the first three columns have the same values as what, the previous record? any record? any adjacent record?  You get different results for each but your expected output doesn't distinguish.

Answer (score 1):

To remove lines whose 4th field is `-` you could simply do.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next} a[$1,$2,$3]>1 && $4=="-"' Input_file Input_file
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks again. I only want to remove rows with 4th field value = "-" , if there is another column with the same first 3 column values..

Comment: @td17, Ok now I got it, please check my edited solution and lemme know on same, note Input_file is being read 2 times here.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I made a bit change since I want to keep line 2-4: awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next} !(a[$1,$2,$3]>1 && $4=="-")' .

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;/^(\s*(\s\S+){3})\s-\n\1/D;s/^((\s*(\s\S+){3}).*)\n\2\s-$/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Append the next line to the current line and if the first three fields of the first line match the first three fields of the second line and the fourth field of the first line is `-`, delete the first line and repeat. However, if the first three fields of the first line match the first three fields of the second line and the fourth field of the second line is `-`, replace both lines by the first and repeat. Otherwise, print then delete the first line and repeat.